# In Ruby, how would I find all .csv files in a folder and print out path to the files that contain the word "meh"?

Tags: ruby

Title pretty much says it all, looking to search for all .csv files and puts out a list of all files with the word meh in the name.  Assume there are a few.

Comment: Hello! What have you tried? We can help you to solve your doubts, but stack overflow is not a code factory.

Comment: I can do a .glob to search for all of the .csv files, but trying to get to print out all of the files that match a certain criteria is where I am getting caught up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**

This method is significantly more direct and efficient:

```
d = Dir.new('.')
d.entries.select do |e| 
  /^.+\.csv$/.match(e) && IO.readlines(e).grep(/meh/).length > 0
end
```

---

This should do it assuming you want to search the current directory

```
d = Dir.new('.')

# This will find all files whose path ends in .csv
csvs = d.entries.select {|e| /^.+\.csv$/.match(e)}

# This will find all .csv files that contain one or more instance 
# of the pattern /meh/
mehs = csvs.select do |e| 
  f = File.open(e)
  [*f.each_line].grep(/meh/).length > 0
end
```